# expand strings as algebraic expressions

Tags: python, string

I have a set of simple strings, that represents some DSL:

```
my_str = ['("word 1" + "word 2") * "word 3"',
          '("word 1" + "word 2") * ("word 3" + "word 4")',
          '(("word 1" + "word 2") * ("word 3" + "word 4")) * "word 5"',
         ]
```

I was trying (and failing badly) to change these to a more straight forward form such as

```
a = foo(my_str)
a= [
 '("word 1" * "word 3") + ("word 2" * "word 3")',
 '("word 1" * "word 3") + ("word 1" * "word 4") + ("word 2" * "word 3") + ("word 2" * "word 4")',
 '("word 1" * "word 3" * "word 5") + ("word 1" * "word 4" * "word 5") + ("word 2" * "word 3" * "word 5") + ("word 2" * "word 4" * "word 5")',
]
```

May be its something simple but I can't seem to get my head around the logic.

Comment: This *isn't* simple.  I have read Lisp textbooks that devote multiple chapters to the task of building a simple symbolic-algebra manipulator -- and the task is significantly simpler in Lisp than in Python.  So, first, don't panic, it's not that you can't do it, it's just that you've taken a bigger bite than you realized.  Second, go to your friendly local public library and get yourself a Lisp textbook and work through those chapters *in Lisp* and then come back to the task in Python.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`pyparsing`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/2.1.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok In the end I used a combination of sympy and pyparsing. 
I used pyparsing to understand the relationships and hierarchies between variables, and then sympy to create and expand the expression.

Some one interested in a bit over-done code can have a look at the [gist](https://gist.github.com/fahaddaniyal/1a1ec377c3a02903d400cb3de88899e9) here.